# How to calculate days of weeks between two dates with SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

For instance, given startDate and endDate of a class for a semester, and days that this class meets (Monday, Wednesday, Friday), is there a function I could use to pre-populate a database with an entry for each potential class session? I am relatively new to java/android and SQLite.

Something like:

```
String[] mathDays = {Monday, Wednesday, Friday};

populateDatabase("4/28/14", "5/09/14", mathDays);

populateDatabase(String sDate, String eDate, String[] daysOfWeek) {
   //calculate each date to list
       daysList

   //put to database
   for (date d: daysList)
        //put the day, date, isAttended, isCancelled
    }
```

So that the database would look like:

```
Day: Monday, Date: 4/28/14, isAttended: False, isCancelled: False;
Day: Wednesday, Date: 4/30/14, isAttended: False, isCancelled: False;
Day: Friday, Date: 5/2/14, isAttended: False, isCancelled: False;
//etc...
```

Comment: do you ask about how to filter dates or how build a database ,, your question is misleading !!

Comment: I suppose I am asking how to filter dates, not sure what you mean by that. I do not need to know how to put the values in the database. I need to know how I could get a list of mondays, wednesdays, and fridays, as well as their individual dates between a start date like 4/28 and an end date like 5/09.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [GregorianCalendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) and [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) classes.

You can create two instances for the start and end dates then simply use the `add(...)` method to add one day at a time to the start date until you get to the end date. Example...

```
// When you first create calDate, set it to the start date
// then increment in a loop until you reach the end date.
calDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Each time you do that you can then use the `get(...)` method to find out what the day is. Example...

```
int dayOfWeek = calDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Note from the constants in the `Calendar` class that Sunday has an int value of 1 with Monday as 2 etc.

In your example code you use `String[] daysOfWeek` but as the `Calendar` class uses int values I suggest you change that to `int[]` .

Comment: Great advice, thank you. I was able to implement these suggestions into a working method.